# Getting this error in sub-query: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question of What is the average number of books published per author in the database?

sample data from books category:

```
TITLE                           CATEGORY
------------------------------ ------------
BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY  FITNESS
REVENGE OF MICKEY              FAMILY LIFE
BUILDING A CAR WITH TOOTHPICKS CHILDREN
DATABASE IMPLEMENTATION        COMPUTER
COOKING WITH MUSHROOMS         COOKING
HOLY GRAIL OF ORACLE           COMPUTER
```

I'm using this command :

```
select a.lname, a.fname, count(*) "# of Books"
from books b join bookauthor ba using (isbn)
join author a using (authorid)
group by fname, lname;
```

And it gets me just the total count of all my books, but I also want the average book count of all the authors so I'm trying to use the AVG subquery.

My current code is:

```
select lname, fname, count(*)
from books 
join bookauthor using (isbn)
join author using (authorid)
where count(*) = (
    select avg(count(*))
    from books
)
group by lname, fname;
```

My expected outcome is getting the average number of books publisher per author, but instead, I'm getting the error in line 4.

Comment: Please show us sample data and expected output so we are sure to clearly understand your question.

Comment: Regardless of the rest of the question, joining to the `AUTHOR` table and grouping by first and last name is a big mistake. Since you only need average count per author, you can use `AUTHORID` in the `GROUP BY` clause (so you don't need the author **names** at all anyway); and it is possible to have *different* authors with the same first and last name (but, one hopes, *different* author id). In that case, grouping by first and last name will give you the wrong result.

Comment: How are books with multiple authors treated in your database? How do they appear in the `bookauthor` table? If this is not explained in the homework assignment (or in the textbook you use), you should definitely ask your teacher this question. Too often in class they only cover the simplest, most obvious cases and they don't teach you to ask the hard questions, the ones that really make life difficult when you have an actual job working in this field.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your existing query to a subquery, and use window function `AVG(...) OVER()` to compute the overall average per author.

```
select 
    t.lname, t.fname, t.cnt "# of Books", avg(t.cnt) over() "Avg # of Books"
from (
    select lname, fname, count(*) cnt
    from books
    join bookauthor using (isbn)
    join author using (authorid)
    group by lname, fname, authorid
) t
```

NB :

- I would recommend prefixing the columns in your query with proper table aliases. Being explicit about where each column comes from makes the query easier to understand and to maintain.
- Grouping by `authorid` is safer than full name, because it avoid wrongly grouping together different authors that have the same full name.

Comment: GROUP BY fname, lname? What if two different authors have the same name? The OP is a beginner, he doesn't know better; you should! -1 from me for that.

Comment: @mathguy : sure, thanks for pointing this out... I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: That query, as currently looks like, is invalid.

Comment: @Littlefoot : would you please explain more what looks invalid ?

Comment: Sure. I'll omit what's not relevant to my objection: `select lname, fname, count(*) ... group by authorid`

Comment: @Littlefoot : ah yes of course... so obvious now. I messed up the query when taking into account the (relevant) comment from Mathguy. Fixed, and thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Without a sub-query this can be accomplished with one query with a window function `avg`.

```
select lname, fname, count(*) as "# of Books",avg(count(*)) over() as avg_#_books
from books join bookauthor using (isbn)
join author using (authorid)
group by fname, lname
```

Comment: Group by fname, lname? What if two different authors have the same name? -1 for that. (Understandable from a beginner like the OP; not understandable from a more experienced programmer like you.)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the count in a subquery, and add the average in an outer query:

```
select  sub.*, avg("# of Books") over () as "Avg # Books Per Author"
from    (
        select lname, fname, count(*) "# of Books"
        from books join bookauthor using (isbn)
        join author using (authorid)
        group by fname, lname
        ) sub;
```

The `over ()` window clause tells Oracle to calculate the average over all authors.

Comment: GROUP BY fname, lname? I can understand that from a beginner like the OP, but what is your excuse? -1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

The average number of books published per author is a single number.  You can get this as:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct b.authorid)
from bookauthor b;
```

If you want this on each row along with the count:

```
select a.lname, a.fname, count(*) as num_books,
       avg(count(*)) over () as avg_for_all_authors
from bookauthor ba join
     author a
     using (authorid)
group by a.fname, a.lname
```

Comment: In the second solution: GROUP BY fname, lname? I understand that from a beginner like the OP, but not from a seasoned programmer like you. Not downvoting because the first solution you offered is correct.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use a group function like count (*) in a where condition as you have used there. In such scenarios the easiest option is to use 'having' clause.

select --- from table where conditions.. group by columns having count (*) = conditions..